# Переключить сервис на Https

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https

Нужно переключить сервис Asp.net Core на протокол https.
Прописал в Startup следующее:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
        options.HttpsPort = 58580;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```

В Program есть:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseUrls("http://localhost:58580/", "http://10.5.10.20:58580", "http://v00iurt:58580")
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("10.5.10.20"), 58580);
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
    })
```

Подскажите, у кого есть опыт?

Comment: Для начала нужно понять: это у вас продакшн приложение или просто играетесь, потому что вообще-то kestrel вендор не рекомендует устанавливать в продакшен-окружении. Можете ставить IIS, можете ставить за nginx свой kestrel и обмен между nginx и kestrel делать по http, а клиенту Https будет обеспечивать nginx... но вот так в Program.cs обычно настраивают под настолько конкретное окружение... обычно это всё в Startup.cs находится, плюс вам вероятно понадобится AddCors раз у вас api. Смотрели вообще типовые примеры решений в студии, там же готовые образцы есть.

Comment: @AK , спасибо. В итоге порешали все на стороне nginx'а. Но все равно был бы признателен за ссылки)

Comment: Ваш `UseKestrel(... Listen)` перекрывает `UseUrls`. Используйте что-то одно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS настраивается отдельно для каждой конечной точки:

```
options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("10.5.10.20"), 58580, ep => ep.UseHttps());
```

А Https Redirection надо настраивать только в том случае, когда у вас есть сразу две конечные точки (HTTP и HTTPS), и вы желаете перенаправить пользователей с первой на вторую.

Comment: Пишет что не содержит определения для Listen

Comment: @СергейТатевосян а куда вы его дели? У вас в вопросе `Listen` тоже используется, почему там не пишет?

Comment: Все ок, не там прописывал.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно понять: это у вас продакшн приложение или просто играетесь, потому что вообще-то kestrel вендор не рекомендует ([1](https://habr.com/en/post/332920/), [2](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0)) устанавливать в продакшен-окружении:

> Главная причина, по которой следует использовать обратный прокси
>   сервер — безопасность. Kestrel относительно нов и ещё не имеет полного
>   комплекта защиты от атак.
>
> Ещё одна причина, по которой следует использовать обратный
>   прокси-сервер — наличие на сервере нескольких приложений, использующих
>   один порт. Kestrel не поддерживает разделение одного порта между
>   несколькими приложениями.

Можете ставить IIS, можете ставить за nginx свой kestrel и обмен между nginx и kestrel делать по http, а клиенту Https будет обеспечивать nginx...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но вот так в Program.cs обычно настраивают под настолько конкретное окружение... обычно это всё в Startup.cs находится, плюс вам вероятно понадобится AddCors раз у вас api. Смотрели вообще типовые примеры решений в студии, там же готовые образцы есть.

Также посмотрите варианты деплоя asp.net core приложений на сайте вендора:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2